# How to make jmeter to wait until full page load

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do performance testing of a web application. As soon as I execute, I see the success message with response code as 200 but when I go to response tab and clicking on respective page, page content shows empty.

In this case, how can i make Jmeter to wait till complete page load?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to tick `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` box at "Advanced" tab of the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults/)), this way JMeter will parse the initial response and download all related images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.

   [image]
2. As per [JMeter project](http://jmeter.apache.org/) main page:

   > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

   So if your page content is partially or fully loaded via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests you need to add HTTP Request sampler(s) to simulate these JavaScript-driven calls. If there is more than one call - consider placing the requests under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) to properly mimic asynchronous concurrent nature of the AJAX calls. The response you're looking for will appear under one of the samplers. You can install the Parallel Controller using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)